# Zend_Service_Twitter & Zend_Oauth_Token_Access behind proxy?

Tags: http, zend-framework, proxy

I'm currently stuck with some of Zend's methods, im trying to make a simple Zend_Service_Twitter request through a proxy, however i keep getting:

> Unable to Connect to tcp://api.twitter.com:80. Error #0:
>   php_network_getaddresses: gethostbyname failed.

I am able to do http calls with the Zend_Http_Client library by itself, so I believe my problem is with the code where I pass the httpClient instance to the Zend_Service_Twitter... But enough rant i guess, basically I have the following:

```
   $config = array(
                'adapter' => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',
                'proxy_host' => self::PROXY_HOST,
                'proxy_port' => self::PROXY_PORT,
                'timeout' => 240,
            );
$httpClient = new Zend_Http_Client(self::TWITTER_API_URL, $config);

            $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access;
            $token->setParams(array(
                Zend_Oauth_Token_Access::TOKEN_PARAM_KEY => self::TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN,
                Zend_Oauth_Token_Access::TOKEN_SECRET_PARAM_KEY => self::TWITTER_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET
            ));


            $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
                        'username' => 'MYUSERNAME',
                        'accessToken' => $token
                    ));
            $twitter->getHttpClient($httpClient);
            $response = $twitter->account->rateLimitStatus();
```

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but the error thrown is sent in the last line of code: $response = $twitter->account->rateLimitStatus();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While taking a closer look at the Zend_Service_Twitter class, all you need to do in order to set up the proxy parameters is this:

```
$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
                        'username' => 'MYUSERNAME',
                        'accessToken' => $token
                    ));

 $twitter->setLocalHttpClient($twitter->getHttpClient($httpClient));
```

($httpClient being an instance of Zend_Http_Client which contains your proxy configuration)